# Null Response with okhttp3

Tags: java, okhttp

so I coded this class to Download URLs but it's returning Null Response
I tried to debug but didn't understand anything

```
package com.example.instaup;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class Downloader
{
    private String myResponse;

    public String DownloadText(String url)
    {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build();
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        myResponse = response.body().toString();
                    }
                }
            });
        return myResponse;
    }
}
```

Can Someone Help me? I'm kinda new to this

Comment: Can you add some more context to where you're running this code, the version of okhttp you're using and the stacktrace of the exception you're getting? This would help pinpoint where the code is failing

Answer (score 0):

You should reuse the client, and use the synchronous form `execute` instead of the enqueue callback API which returns almost immediately before the request has finished.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class Downloader {
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  public String DownloadText(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    try (Response myResponse = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
      return myResponse.body().string();
    }
  }
}
```